# Instapaper/Readability-like app with seamless Nook support?

Tags: webapp-rec

[Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com) and [Readability](http://www.readability.com) both have the insanely cool feature of sending your articles to read directly to your Kindle, so you can read them offline on an e-ink screen.

Is there an app or service that has similar support for Nook?

I know Instapaper can generate ePubs for the Nook, but to my knowledge they need to be manually downloaded and are not automatically sent to the Nook. I would be OK with a desktop solution that automatically synchronizes the Nook with the service while plugged in to USB; not as convenient as over-the-air, but better than manually downloading ePubs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) is an open source ebook management software.
Using calibre's built in news schedule system you can schedule downloads for both instapaper and readitlater, I have personally used Calibre with readitlater and found it to work well,

Only problem with readitlater support is no pictures (its based on the text view). Depending on what you browse this probably isn't a problem. I can't speak for the quality of the instapaper sync, but it is listed as an option.

This would unfortunately be a desktop solution, and would require you to plug the nook in regularly to use it.

In Calibre's schedule news download menu, you can find these at the bottom under "Unknown" in the language drop down.